# JQuery, Find results in table column

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to find the results in a table column if its set in my function below, most of this was setup by someone else, ive just added some extras into it, my final one is searching 1 column only by name set in the thead but alas in its current edition nothing happens at all :|

thanks for any help

USAGE

```
<a href='javascript:searchTable("Bob", "table",1,"Name");'>Test</a>
```

TABLE

```
    <table id="table" class="table">
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id="blank">&nbsp;</th>
            <th id="Name">Name</th>
            <th id="Dept">Department</th>
            <th id="JobTitle">Job Title</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>IT</td>
            <td>IT Support</td>
          </tr>    
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Fred</td>
            <td>Finance</td>
            <td>Finance Man</td>
          </tr>     
       </tbody>
   </table
```

FUNCTION

```
function searchTable(inputVal, tablename,starts, column) {
    var table = $(tablename);
    table.find('tr:not(.header)').each(function (index, row) {
        if (column != '') {
            //Columnname
            var Cells = $(row).find('td').eq(column);
        } else {
            //AllCells
            var Cells = $(row).find('td');
        }
        if (Cells.length > 0) {
            var found = false;
            Cells.each(function (index, td) {
                if (starts == 1) {
                    var regExp = new RegExp((starts ? '^' : '') + inputVal, 'i');
                } else {
                    var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                }

                if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (found == true) $(row).show().removeClass('exclude'); else 
            $(row).hide().addClass('exclude');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is `column` passed to the function as?

Comment: for example
<a href='javascript:searchTable("Bob", "table",1,"Name");'>Test</a>
column is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're passing the `column` as a string, you need get the corresponding elements index:

```
var Cells = $(row).find('td:eq(' + $('#' + column).index() + ')');
```

The above presumes that you're matching based on the `id`, if you're matching based on the text within the `<th>` you could use the `:contains` selector:

```
$(row).find('td:eq(' + $(table.prop('id') + ' th:contains(' + column + ')').index() + ')');
```

If you can control and modify the function calls, the best thing to do would be to just pass the elements index directly to the function:

```
javascript:searchTable("Bob", "table", 1, 1); <-- Would be the "Name" column
```

That way, you won't have to do any of the above.

By the way, your table selector is incorrect based on your comment, not sure if that's just a typo on your part?

```
var table = $(tablename);
```

Should be:

```
var table = $('#' + tablename);
```

Comment: i did $(row).find('td:eq(' + $(table + ' th:contains(' + column + ')').index() + ')'); and im getting SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught 
jquery-1.6.2.js, line 4083 character 2

Comment: Ahh good catch. You need to pass it the table `table` id, the above is passing the jQuery object, I've edited my answer. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to control but you can use this to loop through rows and get the values of cells.

```
$("#table>tbody>tr").each(function(){
 var name= $(this).children("td").eq(1).html();//Name
 var department=  $(this).children("td").eq(2).html();//Department
 var jobTitle=  $(this).children("td").eq(2).html();//Job Title
  alert(name);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/uvefud/1/edit

Edit:
You can try this searchTable function.

```
function searchTable(name,tableName,row,column){

var $Tds= $("#"+tableName+">tbody>tr").eq(row-1).children("td");
 if(column=="Name"){
    $Tds.eq(1).html(name);
  }
  else if(column=="Dept"){
    $Tds.eq(2).html(name);
  }
  else if(column=="JobTitle"){
    $Tds.eq(3).html(name);
  }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W9zpq/2/

**Usage:** This will update the name column of 2nd row of tbody to 'Bob'

```
searchTable("Bob", "table",2,"Name")
```

Comment: This script already returns the values of cells, but it returns all values in its current state, i want it to return values from a specfic column, if the column name is set